# How to get SQL results as Different sets in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following requirement: by using SQL `IN` clause with getting top 20 record. My query is

```
Select CatId,Name,Color 
from Table1 
where CatId in (10,11,12)
```

and results are like

```
 CatId  | Name   | Color
 ------- -------- ------
 10       Name1    Blue
 10       Name2    red
 10       Name3    Blue
 11       Name4    Blue
 10       Name5    red
 12       Name6    Blue
 11       Name7    Blue
 12       Name8    Blue
 .......
```

But I need results like sets **sets** which has **CatIds in (10,11,12)**

```
CatId  | Name   | Color
 ------- -------- ------
 10       Name1    Blue
 11       Name4    Blue
 12       Name6    Blue
 10       Name2    Red
 11       Name7    red
 12       Name8    Blue   
 ......
```

Is there any way in SQL query please tell me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a query with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
Select CatId, Name, Color
from (
   Select CatId, Name, Color,
          row_number() over (partition by CatId order by Name) AS rn 
   from mytable 
   where CatId in (10,11,12)) as t
order by rn, Name
```

The above query uses `ROW_NUMBER` with `PARTITION BY` clause, so as to enumerate records withing slices of the same `CatId`. So, for example, records that have `CatId = 10` are assigned numbers `1, 2, 3, ...`, then records with `CatId = 11` are similarly assigned number `1, 2, 3, ...` and so not. Using these numbers we can create an ordering like the one required.

Comment: Can you please explain the above query?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I got the working of ROW_NUMBER  and PARTITION BY  but how it will display in pattern like 10,11,12,10,11,12

Comment: @Harshil Records are ordered like this 10, 11, 12 {rn=1} / 10, 11, 12 {rn=2} / etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand,

try this (I assume CatId is numeric):

```
Select CatId, Name, Color 
from Table1 T
where CatId in (10,11,12)
order by CatId + CatId * ISNULL(
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 T1
    WHERE T.CatId = T1.CatId
    AND T.Name > T1.Name), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select CatId,Name,Color 
from Table1 
where CatId in (10,11,12) order by Color, CatID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY catId ORDER BY catId ) as rowNumber, * FROM Table1
WHERE catId in (10,11,12)
ORDER BY rowNumber
```